# Google Sheets Conditional format on entire column

Tags: google-sheets

This has been answered

I currently have it set so if anything in A1:Z10000 reads red then it will be highlighted in Red with conditional format. the only problem is that only applies to the single sell that reads Red. What I would like for it to do is if A9 says Red then all of 9:9 is highlighted in Red.

Thanks for any help with this

A public functioning version of the sheet can be found here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N13pkCZmJ6rHFXjH3rl-dPHNdo_N4zQbH5jps1jIQoc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this I used =$A2="Red"

Comment: I switched the range to A2:Z530 and if you look at the google sheet it works, Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Sory but how is that? it works with the A1:Z10000 range and now when A9 reads Red 9:9 is all highlighted in red?

Comment: come on man Don't downvote me just because you could not figure it out

Comment: but once again thanks for your help in trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Please try a CF formula rule of:

```
=countif($A1:$Z1,"red")
```

with the Apply to range as you show.

Choose formatting also.

Comment: Thanks, I applied that as a custom formula and it did not work

Comment: I attempted that with Yellow to no luck in the google sheet

Comment: Just Changed that and no effect, but nice catch